# how do i configure my mysql database that does not respond?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I was working on a Laravel project using mysql database as a database server.I have my project files and databases here in the server.I need them. Mysql database was working properly and when i try to run mysql server next time it does not respond.
I have look in the help tutorials and codes.
From there, I rename previous  data folder to old_data folder and created new data folder inside mysql folder.
I save all the files from backup folder to new data folder.
I save all the database folder except(phpmyadmin, mysql, performance_schema) to new data folder. and lastly i copy the ibdata1 file from old_data folder to new data folder and replace the old files.and still mysql database does not work.
[initial error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2WEy.jpg)
[current xampp sever control page which donot initialize mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmtLK.png)
[current error log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4aoi.png)

Comment: Since the question is only about starting mysql in xampp, I've removed the php and laravel tags.

Comment: i have not found the solution to my problem.i have summarize and edited the problem . and attach the error pictures too.